# Open Cl.I just need to convert the code to using two work items in the for loop. Currently it uses one

Tags: opencl

```
spmv_csr_scalar_kernel(const int num_rows,
                       const int * ptr,
                       const int * indices,
                       const float * data,
                       const float * x,
                       float * y )
{
    int row = get_global_id(0);
    if(row < num_rows)
    {
        float dot = 0;
        int row_start = ptr[row];
        int row_end = ptr[row+1];
        for (int jj = row_start; jj < row_end; jj++)
        {  
            dot += data[jj] * x[indices[jj]];
        }
        y[row] += dot;
    }
}
```

Above is the Open Cl code for multiplying a sparse matrix in CSR format with a Column vector.It uses one global work item per for loop.Can anybody help me in using two work items in each for loop.I am new to open cl and get a lot of issues if I modify even the smallest thing.Please help me.This a part of my project.I made it this parallel but I wanna make it more parallel.Please help me if you can.plzzzz

A single work item executes the for loop from row_start to row_end.I want that this row or for loop is further divided into two parts each executed by a single work item.How do I go on accomplishing that?

This is what I could come up with but its returning the wrong output.

```
__kernel void mykernel(__global int* colvector,
                       __global int* val,
                       __global int* result,
                       __global int* index,
                       __global int* rowptr,
                       __global int* sync )
{
    __global int vals[8]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        result[i]=0;
    }
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    int thread_id=get_global_id(0);
    int warp_id=thread_id/2;
    int lane=(thread_id)&1;
    int row=warp_id;

    if(row<4)
    {
        int row_start = rowptr[row];
        int row_end = rowptr[row+1];
        vals[thread_id]=0;

        for (int i = row_start+lane; i<row_end; i+=2)
        {
            vals[thread_id]+=val[i]*colvector[index[i]];
        }

        vals[thread_id]+=vals[thread_id+1];

        if(lane==0)
        {
            result[row] += vals[thread_id];
        }
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the number of work groups and the group id to achieve this.

```
spmv_csr_scalar_kernel(const int num_rows, const int * ptr, const int * indices, const float * data, const float * x, float * y) {

    __local float[64] dot; //local memory for dot product. assumes you want to use up to 64-item workgroups.
    int localId = get_local_id(0); //offest value for jj loop
    int localSize = get_local_size(0); //this is the number of work items computing the jj loop
    int nGroups = get_num_groups(0); //number of workgroups executing this kernel

    for (int row = get_group_id(0); row < num_rows; row += nGroups) {
        dot[localId] = 0;
        int row_start = ptr[row] + localId;
        int row_end = ptr[row + 1];
        for (int jj = row_start; jj < row_end; jj++) {
            dot[localId] += data[jj] * x[indices[jj]];
        }
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        //here's where work item #0 in the group sums the values stored in local memory
        if (localId == 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i < localSize; i++) {
                dot[0] += dot[i];
            }
            y[row] += dot[0]; //only a single write to the global memory location
            barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        }
    }
```

This kernel will use as many workgroups as you want to complete all of the work. (ie groups can work on more than one row) This is done by converting 'if(row < num_rows)' into the 'for(int row...' loop. You may find that a single workgroup with the right number of work items may outperform many small work groups.

I used 64 as a hard coded value for the local memory size. The above kernel will work fine with workgroup sizes up to 64. 64 happens to be optimal on many devices today. You can experiment with other hard coded values, or allocate the local memory by passing in a __local param.

Comment: Friend ,your code is not returning the correct output.Its returning 230 for first index of result array and all remaining indices are 0

Comment: It is returning different values for different settings of work group,work item,local item.How should i set the enqueundrangekernel(.......) call?

Comment: It is returning different answers for different local and global item combinations.none is correct

Comment: try enqueundrangekernel with only a single global work item (and a small matrix if you can). If the results are correct, try 16 global with 16 local work items to test out a single workgroup.